# Django Serializer overide "name" and cannot send name value to DB

Tags: django, serialization, overriding

I got this code:

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
icon = serializers.CharField(source='icon_before')
name = serializers.SerializerMethodField('_get_device_name')

class Meta:
    model = models.Device
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'host', 'icon', 'status', 'featured', 'pin', 'room', 'target', 'series', 'type')

@staticmethod
def _get_device_name(obj):
    return '%s - %s - %s' % (obj.name, obj.target, obj.room.name)
```

and I am trying to understand what can I do to override name but to let django send name value from restapi post into db, right now it doesn't, it will if I remove the "name = override".
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have a different field for what you want to achieve. Your _get_device_name is intended for read only right ? Something like :

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    icon = serializers.CharField(source='icon_before')
    output_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='_get_device_name')
```